# SQL Statement to merge two tables with multiple records

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to merge two objects using Automation Studio in Marketing Cloud so a customers opportunities/or no opportunities are all in the one table.

I think this spreadsheet i created will make sense.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DqI63WYpD2yc1pkY4ulDCE9uhC1ABcT5Eb9yhFM8j4k/edit?usp=sharing

There are three types of accounts and opps.
1) Accounts with 1 opp
2) Accounts with many opps
3) Accounts with no opps

I need to have all three types of customers appear in the one table with all opps associated.

Hope this makes sense!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a [**left join**](https://katiekodes.com/sql-every-join/#left-outer-join) will do the trick:

```
select
  a.email
, a.contactID
, o.opp
, o.name
from Account_Salesforce a
left join Opportunity_Salesforce o on o.contactid = a.contactid
```

You'll need to make sure the primary key on the target data extension defines uniqueness with more columns than just `email` and `contactID`.

Comment: Thanks Adam! what would an example of a further primary key be? The SQL works but only brings in 1 opportunity, not all of them if 1 or more

Comment: It shouldn't be returning just one row, if the schema is as you illustrated in your worksheet.  I'd probably recommend no PK on the target -- every field nullable and then do use an overwrite as the action on your query.